# Can't Query Product Package Server Relational & Count Properties

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

In my Ruby script, I can't seem to get the **Softlayer_Product_Package_Server** relational properties from the [SoftLayer API endpoint](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server). My Ruby code:

```
packageServerList = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server'].getAllObjects
packageServerList.each do |packageServer|
     packageServer['package']
end
```

The `packageServer['package']` just gives me a null object. Some of the other relations have the same issue ("brand", "catalog", "itemPrice"), but "item" seems to work. Taken from:

This is confusing because the [REST request](https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects?objectMask=mask[package]) works and shows the data from a 'package' object mask.

Comment: Your example for the REST reuqest seems to require a password. Also what Ruby library do you use for accessing the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get relational or/and count properties, it's necessary to use an [Object Masks](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-masks), please make the below change in your code:

```
packageServerList = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server'].object_mask('mask[package, brand, caralog]').getAllObjects
```

**References:**

- [Using Object Masks - Ruby](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Ruby#Using_Object_Masks)